# Get the name of the python 3.x method that was called inside of __call__

Tags: python, reflection

I'm trying to add a method to a class whenever it is called.
For instance:

```
class X(callable):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method_called = self.get_method_name()

        if method_called not in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[method_called] = self.generic_function

        super().__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def generic_function(self):
        print("I'm So Generic")

    def a(self):
        print('a')

    def get_method_name(self):
        #get the name of the method trying to be called
        method_name = ?????
        return method_name

def main():
    x = X()
    #should create a method nonexistant_method that acts like generic_function
    x.nonexistant_method()

main()
```

I realize that this might be an odd thing to want to do, but it's part of a tool that I'm building for some research. Is this possible? Or perhaps there is a better place to accomplish this than in __call__?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to override `__getattr__` rather than `__call__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__call__` is for when the object itself is called, like `x()`. `x.nonexistant_method()` *(sic)* never calls `x`'s `__call__` method; it instead would call `nonexistant_method`'s `__call__` (if that method existed).

What you want in this case is `__getattr__`, I think. When an attribute is accessed that does not exist, `__getattr__` is called. In this case you simply want to return your `generic_function`.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self.generic_function
```

Comment: I expanded on your explanation of how one might accomplish what he was looking for, using `__getattr__` -- I hope that's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

kindall is exactly right, you likely want `__getattr__`.

Here is an example class that works the way I think you want yours to work:

```
class X:
    def make_missing_method(self, name):
        def missing_method(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Self object:", self)
            print("Method name:", name)
            print("Method args:", [args, kwargs])
        return missing_method

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.make_missing_method(name)
```

This may confusing, but it's pretty straightforward.

First thing to note, python functions are objects, and can be passed around like anything else.

We take advantage of that here, by creating `make_missing_method`, which is simply a function **that returns a function**.  (This is known as a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)).

We can call `X.make_missing_method('foo')` and verify this:

```
x = X()
f = x.make_missing_method('foo')
print(type(f))  # <class 'function'>
```

And as noted by kindall, when you attempt to access an instance attribute that does not exist (with the `.` notation), `__getattr__` is called with the name you tried to access as an argument.

We can combine these two things, to create a class that will allow you to call a previously undefined method on an instance, and have it function as you expected.

So given the class above, we can write:

```
x = X()
x.foo()
```

Output:

```
Self object: <__main__.X object at 0x00000000021E0BE0>
Method name: foo
Method args: [(), {}]
```

Note that `foo` is not defined in the `X` class above, but `missing_method` was still called appropriately.  And from inside `missing_method` we have access to the invoking instance (through `self`), the name of the method that was attempted (through `name`) and the arguments that were passed.

To see the arguments in action, you could write:

```
x = X()
x.bar(1, 2, third="three")
```

Output:

```
Self object: <__main__.X object at 0x00000000021E0BE0>
Method name: bar
Method args: [(1, 2), {'third': 'three'}]
```

Again, `bar` isn't explicitly defined as a method, but calling `x.bar(...)` works as if it was.